# How to Get Number in String By JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, split, numbers

I'm working on a project. I have a analog clock. It was created jQuery. This clock is placing in a div element and when i want to get numbers, the result is like below.

```
Days0Hours0Minutes0Seconds2
```

But i want only number. Like this:

```
numberArray[0] = 0; // days
numberArray[1] = 0; // hours
numberArray[2] = 0; // minutes
numberArray[3] = 2; // seconds
```

How can i do that?

Thanks everybody!

Edit:

when use below code:

```
$("#PageOpenTimer").text(); // for div
```

result:

```
Days0Hours0Minutes0Seconds2
```

when use below code:

```
$("#PageOpenTimer").html(); // for div
```

result:

```
<div class="time_circles"><canvas width="500" height="125"></canvas><div class="textDiv_Days" style="top: 44px; left: 0px; width: 125px;"><h4 style="font-size: 9px;">Days</h4><span style="font-size: 35px;">0</span></div><div class="textDiv_Hours" style="top: 44px; left: 125px; width: 125px;"><h4 style="font-size: 9px;">Hours</h4><span style="font-size: 35px;">0</span></div><div class="textDiv_Minutes" style="top: 44px; left: 250px; width: 125px;"><h4 style="font-size: 9px;">Minutes</h4><span style="font-size: 35px;">0</span></div><div class="textDiv_Seconds" style="top: 44px; left: 375px; width: 125px;"><h4 style="font-size: 9px;">Seconds</h4><span style="font-size: 35px;">1</span></div></div>
```

Comment: `str.match(/\d+/g)`

Comment: What code have you tried, what output did you get, what output were you looking to get, what research have you done on the subject?

Comment: its better to rely on jquery plugin's method which you have used to form the clock on your page to get the information needed. It will be quite easy by that way instead of parsing it manually. Do you have any idea which plugin you have used here?

Comment: yeah! https://github.com/wimbarelds/TimeCircles

Comment: `$(".example").TimeCircles().getTime();` will give you number of seconds passed. So using that number you can count days,hr,min and sec.

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't work! :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look at this approach which uses TimeCircles plugin's method `getTime()` to get the total seconds:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".example").TimeCircles();

  $(".start").click(function() {
    $(".example").TimeCircles().start();
  });
  $(".stop").click(function() {
    $(".example").TimeCircles().stop();
  });

  $(".getTime").click(function() {
    var totalSeconds = $(".example").TimeCircles().getTime();
    totalSeconds = Math.ceil(Math.abs(totalSeconds));

    var seconds = Math.floor((totalSeconds % 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((totalSeconds % 3600) / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor((totalSeconds % 86400) / 3600);
    var days = Math.floor((totalSeconds % (86400 * 30)) / 86400);
    
    alert(days + " - "+hours+ " - "+minutes+ " - "+seconds);
    

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/inc/TimeCircles.js"></script>
<link href="http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/inc/readme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button class="getTime">click to Get Time</button>
<button class="btn btn-success start">Start</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger stop">Stop</button>
<div class="example"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Regex to extract the values you want

```
^Days(\d+)Hours(\d+)Minutes(\d+)Seconds(\d+)$
```

and then use `$("#PageOpenTimer").text();` to get the value and test with the regex to get the array of numbers.

[Tested in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HsdynE/1)

Result will be:

Full match  0-27    `Days0Hours0Minutes0Seconds2`

- Group 1. 4-5 `0`
- Group 2. 10-11   `0`
- Group 3. 18-19   `0`
- Group 4. 26-27   `2`